# How to receive emails on behalf of an externally hosted domain

Tags: email, server, google-compute-engine

I have a debian 6.0.7 (squeeze) server, and a Google Compute Engine Centos 7 instance, Now I have sites hosted on the GCE for example blablabla.com, I need to configure my local debian to be able to receive and send emails for my blablabla.com site on the GCE so as it appears as if blablabla.com is hosted on my local debian server, Any help on how to achieve this please

Comment: Questions about servers and email are not programming questions as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should delete this and ask, instead, on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Quick answer: the external domain owner needs to configure his DNS to point the MX records to your mail server.

Comment: @Robert, i understand that, but do i have to do any more configurations on my local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems that is not an usual configuration, but in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) you can find some options that can be implemented within GCE instances, but keep in mind that port 25 is not open.